# Nested order by/order by within order by in SQL

Tags: sql

I am looking to sort my sql results via an sql query with presumably some sort of nested order by/order by within an order by clause

I have the following data:

```
TERM      USER      ITEM_NO     SCORE
man       sam       2           NULL
man       sam       1           170
man       jerry     1           100 
man       jerry     2           NULL
man       sam       3           NULL
```

and I wish to obtain the following order for the results:

```
TERM      USER      ITEM_NO     SCORE
man       sam       1           170
man       sam       2           NULL
man       sam       3           NULL
man       jerry     1           100
man       jerry     2           NULL
```

The results must be sorted firstly by the score (stored only in item_no 1 for each user) descending. However any further items created by that user for the seleted term must also be picked up and inserted directly following and in item_no order.

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE term = 'man' ORDER BY SCORE DESC, ITEM_NO ASC
```

...however this simply results as follows:

```
TERM      USER      ITEM_NO     SCORE
man       sam       1           170
man       jerry     1           100
man       sam       2           NULL
man       jerry     2           NULL
man       sam       3           NULL
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Does this give you what you are looking for? `...ORDER BY USER DESC, SCORE DESC, ITEM_NO ASC`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as the score must be the primary sorting device. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT MAX(Score)
   FROM TEST t2
   WHERE t2.Term = t1.Term AND t2.User = t1.User GROUP BY t2.Term, t2. User) as max_score
FROM test t1
WHERE term = 'man'
ORDER BY max_score DESC, ITEM_NO ASC
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00c34/1)

Or another solution with the same results (I think it has better performance, but you'd need to do some testing about that):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
JOIN
  (SELECT t2.Term, t2.User, score FROM Test t2 WHERE t2.Item_No = 1) t3
ON t1.Term = t3.Term AND t1.User = t3.User
ORDER BY t3.score DESC, t1.Item_No;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00c34/23)

Comment: This is an excellent solution for MySql. For MS SQL you'll need to make a minor change and put brackets around [user] since it's a reserved word.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Both of these work, however in the event that the score is the same for both users unfortunately the order breaks down. After playing around though I discovered that if I change the ORDER BY clause as follows: `ORDER BY t3.score DESC, t1.User, t1.Item_No` the grouping of the results remains.

Comment: Re: my previous comment, the alteration to the ORDER BY clause relates to the second solution.

Answer (score -2):

select USER, ITEM_NO, SCORE  from 'TABLE' order by 2, 3;

-- 2 is Column USER, 3 is Column ITEM_NO

Comment: 2 is column `ITEM_NO` and column 3 is `SCORE`